# Calculate all the values in textfile

Tags: c#, text-files

I have to make a program which allows the admin to calculate total revenues for each business type.

I have stored all the gained revenues for each type in separate text files ie. .Mobile.txt , .Kiosk.txt , .Daily.txt

the content for each type in the text file are like this

```
10
60
30
```

so far this is the code i've generated, but it still doesn't work

```
 private void Report_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<double> kiosk = new List<double>();
        List<double> daily = new List<double>();
        List<double> mobile = new List<double>();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@".Kiosk.txt"))
        {
            kiosk.Add(double.Parse(line));
        }

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@".Mobile.txt"))
        {
            mobile.Add(Double.Parse(line));

        }

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@".Daily.txt"))
        {
            daily.Add(Double.Parse(line));
        }

        double sum_kiosk = kiosk.Sum();
        double sum_mobile = mobile.Sum();
        double sum_daily = daily.Sum();

        MessageBox.Show("Total revenue kiosk:" + sum_kiosk + "\nTotal revenue mobile:" + sum_mobile + "\nTotal revenue:" + sum_daily);
    }
```

And the error was an exception which states "input string was not in a correct format". I can't seem to find the problem for this one

How to solve this error? or Is there a better alternative to make this feature work?

Comment: _"solving this error"_ - what error is that?

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working? What are the specifics of the exception you are getting?

Comment: @Kevin  "input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: @stuartd  the input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: Are there any blank lines in the file? double.Parse will throw an exception in that case.

Comment: Inspect all the List variables. Breakpoints are always handy when you have errors :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to compute all numbers. and use variable instead of list

```
double mobile = 0;
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"data.txt"))
{
    double temp;
    double.TryParse(line, out temp);
    mobile += temp;
}
```

Comment: @ShafiqNorhisham all values of file will be add up in mobile variable....

Answer (score 0):

The function below uses an anonymous method to do the calculation.

```
    private void processFiles() { 
        var calculateTotal = new Func<String, Double>(filename => {
            if (!File.Exists(filename)) return 0;

            var dAmount = 0D;

            return (
                from line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                let isDouble = double.TryParse(line, out dAmount)
                select dAmount
            ).Sum();
        });

        var kiosk = calculateTotal(@"C:\test\totaltest\kiosk.txt");
        var daily = calculateTotal(@"C:\test\totaltest\daily.txt");
        var mobile = calculateTotal(@"C:\test\totaltest\mobile.txt");
    }
```